# How to see logger output on Xunit.net test? C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit.net

Currently I'm doing this

```
var apiService = new APIService(new Mock<ILogger<APIService>>().Object);
```

But I want to see error output during the tests. My theory is that it should be possible to replace `new Mock<ILogger<APIService>>` by a kind of console logger that shows the output in the tests, but I don't know how to instantiate it.

If I put `Console.WriteLine("foo")` I can see the `foo` message, I would like `Logger.LogError(...)` to behave the same way during the tests, how to achieve that?

I'm using Moq framework: https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/

Comment: 1) Depends on the mocking framework 2) Think twice if you really need that.

Comment: I'm using Moq, also I edited the question. It would be really helpful because there are log of `catch (Exception e) { Logger.LogError(e, "...") }` in the code base. This errors go to Sentry, but during the tests I can't see the errors during development so there are space for false positives (test passing but code is wrong)

Comment: Just write separate tests for each exception,  in every test check that logger is invoked with a proper exception and message. You are shooting your leg by trying to test all cases in one place.

Comment: One thing more, actually you are testing a stub that you pass to the constructor as a parameter, you are not testing the class

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var stubLogger = new Mock<ILogger<APIService>>();

var apiServiceUnderTeest = new APIService(stubLogger);

// Configure moq to check invocations
stubLogger.Setup(mock => mock.LogError(e, "..."));

// Invoke your method that logs something
apiServiceUnderTeest.SomeMethodThatLogsException();

// Test if logger been invoked as you expect
stubLogger.Verify(mock => mock.LogError(), Times.Once());
```

Something like that, not sure as I couldn't test.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I'm interested in see the log messages, in the test output, the "real" test is to check for some side effects on the database. Isn't it possible to just instantiate a logger that call Console.WriteLine(msg)? I'm new to C#